# Declaration of ordered pairs sets in AMPL

Tags: ampl

I have a variable u[i,j,p] where i and j are ordered sets. Specifically I have defined the variable and the sets like

```
  set I;
  set J;
  set P;
  set LINKS within {I,J};
  param u{LINKS,P}
```

in the .mod file. In my .dat I've written:

```
set I := 1 2 3 4;
set J := Factory1 Factory2 Factory3 Factory4
set LINKS := (1,Factory1) (2,Factory1) (3,Factory2) (4,Factory2);
set P:= prod1 prod2 prod3;

param u default 0:=
     [1,Factory1,*] prod1 0.5251 prod2 0.3738
     [2,Factory1,*] prod1 0.5052 prod2 0.3311
     [3,Factory2,*] prod1 0.5555 prod3 0.6666
     [4,Factory2,*] prod3 0.6156 prod4 0.3353;
```

But this gives me errors regarding how u is declared. When trying to follow the AMPL documentation I tried to do

```
param LINKS: u:=
     [1,Factory1,*] prod1 0.5251 prod2 0.3738
     [2,Factory1,*] prod1 0.5052 prod2 0.3311
     [3,Factory2,*] prod1 0.5555 prod3 0.6666
     [4,Factory2,*] prod3 0.6156 prod4 0.3353;
```

But it also gives error.

Answer (score 1):

There are two issues in your code:

1. Missing semicolons in

   ```
   param u{LINKS,P}
   ```

   and

   ```
   set J := Factory1 Factory2 Factory3 Factory4
   ```
2. Use of `prod4` which is not a member of `P`.

Otherwise it looks correct.